# Apply gradient over page without hindering user interaction

Tags: javascript, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Click through a DIV to underlying elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements)

I want to apply a radial CSS gradient over the whole of a webpage without blocking user interaction. The user needs to interact with the page via mouse-over events on elements underneath the gradient. Any way to do this?

Cheers

Comment: Your question is not really clear. Could you specify more clearly what you actually want? What is meant exactly by gradient, a CSS gradient? And where do the mouse-over events occur on?

Comment: @wnstnsmth I understand the question very well. If you just add an extra element to form the gradient overlay, it will consume all mouse events as well.

Comment: Thanks Jan! That's what I wanted.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/pointer-events